# select option selected in loop

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I am trying to get the value from a selectbox. The form is placed multiple times on my page with a php loop (that's why I use classes instead of id's).

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <table>
        <form class="lesmaker">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                    <select name="type" class="type">
                        <option value="open">Open vraag</option>
                        <option value="info">Informatie</option>
                        <option value="discussie">Klassikaal</option>
                        <option value="meerkeuze" selected="selected">Meerkeuze</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                    <select name="media" class="media">
                    <?php foreach($images as $image){if(substr($image,0,1) != '.'){ ?>
                    <option style="background-image:url(<?=$d_images.$image?>)" value="<?=$image?>" <?php if($r_media== $image) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?=$image?></option>
                    <?php }} ?>
                </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </table>
    <table>
        <form class="lesmaker">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                    <select name="type" class="type">
                        <option value="open">Open vraag</option>
                        <option value="info">Informatie</option>
                        <option value="discussie">Klassikaal</option>
                        <option value="meerkeuze" selected="selected">Meerkeuze</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                    <select name="media" class="media">
                    <?php foreach($images as $image){if(substr($image,0,1) != '.'){ ?>
                    <option style="background-image:url(<?=$d_images.$image?>)" value="<?=$image?>" <?php if($r_media== $image) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?=$image?></option>
                    <?php }} ?>
                </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

With jQuery I am trying to get the selected option.

```
    $(function(){
        $('.lesmaker').each(function() {                
            console.log($(this).find('.type').val());
        });
    });
```

The code above is not working. How do I need to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $('.lesmaker').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).find('table tr td').find('.type').val());
  });
});
```

You need to change your HTML to following:

```
  <form class="lesmaker">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">
        <select name="type" class="type">
          <option value="open">Open vraag</option>
          <option value="info">Informatie</option>
          <option value="discussie">Klassikaal</option>
          <option value="meerkeuze" selected="selected">Meerkeuze</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

form needs to be either outside of table or inside of td :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.type').each(function() {
    console.log($('option:selected', this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <form class="lesmaker">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">
        <select name="type" class="type">
          <option value="open">Open vraag</option>
          <option value="info">Informatie</option>
          <option value="discussie">Klassikaal</option>
          <option value="meerkeuze" selected="selected">Meerkeuze</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">
        <select name="type" class="type">
          <option value="open">Open vraag</option>
          <option value="info">Informatie</option>
          <option value="discussie" selected="selected">Klassikaal</option>
          <option value="meerkeuze" >Meerkeuze</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">
        <select name="type" class="type">
          <option value="open">Open vraag</option>
          <option value="info" selected="selected">Informatie</option>
          <option value="discussie" >Klassikaal</option>
          <option value="meerkeuze" >Meerkeuze</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>
```

Just use the class of select and use `$('option:selected', this).val()`

Comment: I've got multiple instances of the same form and I also got other form-select groups in my form (not displayed because I thought it was not relevant, seems that it is though).

Comment: what `for-select groups` can you add it in OP